# Merge duplicate records into 1 records with the same table and table fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have a database table that contains a list of demographic records, some of those participant might have multiple/duplicate records, e.g.

NOTE: 
Gender:
119 = Male
118 = Female

Race:
255 = white
253 = Asian

UrbanRural:
331 = Urban 
332 = Rural

```
participantid, gender, race, urbanrural, moduletypeid, hibernateid, and more fields
1, 119, 0, 331, 1, 1, .....
1, 119, 255, 0, 2, 2, .....
1, 0, 255, 331, 3, 3, .....
1, 119, 253, 331, 0, 4, .....
```

The output should be keep the first hibernateid and the duplicate records will be merge to the first hibernatedid record. If you can do this using function that will check the records if duplicate that would be great, after merged the records it delete the unused duplicate records. Your answer gives me a great idea to resolved this problem. Thanks

Output should be:

```
participantid, gender, race, urbanrural, moduletypeid, hibernateid, and more fields
1, 119, 255, 331, 1, 1, .....
```

Help me guys, Thanks

Comment: Do you have foreign-key references to worry about?

Comment: hibernateid is the unique value.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this in Postgres 9.1+:

```
WITH duplicates AS (
  SELECT desired_unique_key, count(*) AS count_of_same_key, min(st.id) AS keep_id, max(st.id) as delete_id
  FROM source_table st
  GROUP BY desired_unique_key
  HAVING count(*) > 1
),
 deleted_dupes AS (
  DELETE FROM source_table st
  WHERE st.id IN (SELECT(delete_id) FROM duplicates)
)
UPDATE source_table st
  SET field = WHATEVER
  FROM duplicates d
  WHERE st.id = d.keep_id
```

Comment: Where is the source of wc. in last WHERE?

Comment: should have be `st.`, fixed now

Comment: What `SET field = WHATEVER` is used for?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
select participantid, min(gender), min(race), min(urbanrural), 
min(case moduletypeid when 0 then null else moduletypeid end), min(hibernateid), ...
from yourtable
group by participantid
```

It's not clear to me why moduletypeid whould be returned as 1 in your example - I have assumed that 0 in this field is a special case, to be treated as null (hence the case clause).

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help. I updated the description of my question to elaborate the records is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something like this (postgres), I haven't tested it yet though.

```
SELECT dup.id AS dup_id, orig.id AS orig_id
INTO TEMP specialty_duplicates
FROM medical_specialty dup,
        (SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) * FROM medical_specialty ORDER BY name, id) orig
WHERE orig.name = dup.name AND dup.id <> orig.id;


UPDATE doctor_medical_specialty
SET medical_specialty=orig_id
FROM specialty_duplicates
WHERE medical_specialty = dup_id;

DELETE
FROM medical_specialty
WHERE id IN (SELECT dup_id FROM specialty_duplicates);

ALTER TABLE medical_specialty
    ADD UNIQUE (name);
```

The schema is that medical_specialty has id and name, and doctor_medical_specialty references it by id.

The benefit over a CTE (IIUC) is you can merge references in multiple referring tables.

I'm using a temporary table rather than a view so that both deleting and updating are consistent with the same snapshot in time

Answer (score 0):

So you want a query to find/remove duplicates, is that right?

If so, try this:

```
SELECT T1.* FROM table_name T1, table_name T2
WHERE T1.dupe_field = T2.dupe_field
AND T1.other_dupe_field = T2.other_dupe_field
AND T1.primary_key > T2.primary_key;
```

Change the table and field names to suit your own table structure.

Confirm with this SELECT query that it is selecting the dupes you want to remove, and then change it to a DELETE in order to remove the dupes.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help but I'm looking for the merging of records.