# Postgresql (Rails 3) merge rows on column (same table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

First, I've been using mysql for forever and am now upgrading to postgresql. The sql syntax is much stricter and some behavior different, thus my question.

I've been searching around for how to merge rows in a postgresql query on a table such as

```
id      | name        |   amount
0       | foo         | 12
1       | bar         | 10
2       | bar         | 13
3       | foo         | 20
```

and get

```
name        |   amount
foo         | 32
bar         | 23
```

The closest I've found is [Merge duplicate records into 1 records with the same table and table fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437966/merge-duplicate-records-into-1-records-with-the-same-table-and-table-fields)

sql returning duplicates of 'name':

```
 scope :tallied, lambda { group(:name, :amount).select("charges.name AS name,
                              SUM(charges.amount) AS amount,
                              COUNT(*) AS tally").order("name, amount desc") }
```

What I need is

```
 scope :tallied, lambda { group(:name, :amount).select("DISTINCT ON(charges.name) charges.name AS name,
                              SUM(charges.amount) AS amount,
                              COUNT(*) AS tally").order("name, amount desc") }
```

except, rather than returning the first row of a given name, should return mash of all rows with a given name (amount added)

In mysql, appending `.group(:name)` (not needing the initial group) to the select would work as expected.

This seems like an everyday sort of task which should be easy. What would be a simple way of doing this? Please point me on the right path.

P.S. I'm trying to learn here (so are others), don't just throw sql in my face, please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea what RoR is doing in the background, but I'm guessing that `group(:name, :amount)` will run a query that groups by name, amount. The one you're looking for is `group by name`:

```
select name, sum(amount) as amount, count(*) as tally
from charges
group by name
```

If you append `amount` to the `group by` clause, the query will do just that -- i.e. `count(*)` would return the number of times each amount appears per name, and the `sum()` would return that number times that amount.

Comment: This doesn't work wit postgresql, if both `name` and `amount` are not present in the `group by` an error is thrown, when they are present nothing special happens (records with the same name are not combined). p.s. rails does exactly what you expected.

Comment: there will be an error if you're doing `select name, amount, sum(amount) ... group by name`; not if you do `select name, sum(amount) ... group by name`.

Comment: Ah, so the error caused by `select name, amount, sum(amount)` is from using an aggregation function on a selected value? `... sum(amount)` adds all amounts, `select name ... group by name` splits returned rows on distinct name producing the sum of amounts for each name. correct? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: That is correct, yes. Group by will merge rows based on the criteria, and apply the aggregate functions over each of the resulting subsets.